# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() stop to work in debug mode

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10.3

I have an app that I call the method **SKStoreReviewController.requestReview ()** after 10 times that the user performs some action. The prompt stoped to appear even the debug show me that the method **requesrReview** is being called.

What's can be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple docs:

> Although you should call this method when it makes sense in the user
>   experience flow of your app, the actual display of a rating/review
>   request view is governed by App Store policy. Because this method may
>   or may not present an alert, it's not appropriate to call it in
>   response to a button tap or other user action.

The popup will only display sometimes, and it's dictated by the `SKStoreReviewController` as to when this will be, so you can't guarantee it will ever be displayed.